# most recent bitbucket commit and push not showing up?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I recently added, commented, and committed code to bitbucket

```
git commit -am "Add a full_title helper"
git push
```

and the most recent activity that is showing up is from this past September. I took steps to connect to github earlier in the Hartl's tutorial but is there a way to check to ensure that I am still connected to bitbucket?

Answer (score 1):

Run `git remote -v` to see where you are pushing

Then you can manually run a push to a remote by doing `git push bitbucket`(or whatever the remote is called)